# Appium not working on the relevant device

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have 2 devices that connected to the computer
I try to run test script on one device but for some reason, appium run the test on the second device
When I take off the second device, the test runs on the relevant device

Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Did you pass the correct device name in the capabilities ? You have to pass on the device name

Comment: You need to add device id in desire capabilities like:  capabilities.setCapability("usid", "devicesUdid"); you get udid by running command adb devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into list of `adb devices` before execution.
Appium would execute the tests on the available device listed by adb starting from top. 
So when both the devices are connected the `device-1` connected first is generally listed first on the device list and the same would hold the execution unless you remove it and the `device-2` plays the same role.
In-fact your appium logs would read the adb deviceID as well when it would look for the devices.